# PushNotificationIOS register handler called repeatedly

Tags: react-native

I am observing that the `PushNotificationIOS` `register` handler is called repeatedly while running the app on iPhone. I am using `react-native 0.32` and running it on iPhone 5s.

Below is how I am registering the `register` event handler which is pretty standard

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', this.appRegistrationHandlerIos);
```

In the event handler, I am just storing the device token in the database. I am observing that it is called repeatedly like every second. Has anyone else observed it? I added code to remove the event handler in the `register` event handler which seems to have fixed the problem but is that the correct way of doing it. The `register` handler looks like this after the change

```
appRegistrationHandlerIos = (deviceToken) => {
    console.log('Updating the device info')
    // Store the token in the database
    PushNotificationIOS.removeEventListener('register', this.appRegistrationHandlerIos);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info  on where/when you setup the event listener?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have been travelling. I am setting up the event listeners in the `componentWillMount` method of the `App` component that gets rendered in the `index.ios.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering in componentWillMount, the recommended way is to removeEventListener in compononentWillUnmount. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#removeeventlistener

My suggestion would be to set it up only once when the app starts and dispatch actions, in case you are using redux/flux etc.

Comment: This is what I was doing. Registering the event handler in the `componentWillMount` and unregistering the handler in `componentWillUnmount` method but I observed that the `register` event handler was called again and again with the same device token instead of being called just once. I will try to reproduce in a new project and post the code on rnplay.